# Google translate params form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-translate

how can I use html form for detect inserted language in input to translate to other language ?
Using Hebrew(iwrit)-English languages.

```
<form action="http://translate.google.com/translate_t" target="_blank">
   <input type="text" name="text">
   <input type="hidden" value="hp" name="prev">
   <input type="hidden" value="iw" name="hl">
   <input type="hidden" value="y" name="js">
   <input type="hidden" value="" name="file">
   <input type="hidden" value="iw" name="sl">
   <input type="hidden" value="en" name="tl">
   <input type="hidden" value="#" name="history_state0">
   <input type="submit" value="Translate">
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you need it to update live and not on a form submit, you will need to make some sort of request when the textbox to translate changes (http://api.jquery.com/change/), then make the appropriate changes to the form indicating the language.

As for the functionality itself, Google has an API for Translate (https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/libraries). There you will find a JavaScript interface, and that should handle all the heavy lifting for you.

I hope that helps.